# Heroku push rejected - ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm deploying a simple sinatra app to heroku and facing this problem.

```
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
       Bundler Output: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:brick2web.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:brick2web.git'
```

Please have a look at [the github repo for this project](https://github.com/hsgodhia/brick2web).

Note:
Everything works perfect on my local machine. none of these errors occur and the command

```
foreman start
```

starts the server normally with no issues. How do I resolve this issue as it is preventing heroku to complie my app. I think there are some configuration issues that are arising, Is there a way to look into the heroku machine where this app is running and sort things out.
In case this helps please find the output of the command "heroku logs"

```
2014-03-09T18:49:59+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-09T18:50:07.187220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby stream.rb -p 36533`
2014-03-09T18:50:08.102029+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
2014-03-09T18:50:09.368840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-03-09T18:50:09.380511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-09T18:50:09.381418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-09T18:50:11.793334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby stream.rb -p 35440`
2014-03-09T18:50:13.229598+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
2014-03-09T18:50:14.665275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
```

Adding the shebang notation to the main sinatra file didn't help either

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```